# New Activity doesn't show up (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm having trouble finding the option to create a new activity in Android Studio. When I right click on any file and go to "New >" none of the new activities choices show up. Can you help me? Maybe is something very easy and it's in front of my eyes. Thank you

Comment: what version of android studio do you have?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.1.2
Project/Android/App/Res/Layout/New/Activity/Basic Activity
[look image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk55t.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution,
1. Right Click on your package name.
2. Select New->File.
    3. Enter File name what you want and add .java to it.
(Like SecondActivity.java).
    4. Now write className in newly created file
    Like: `public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity{...}`
5. Error occurs on SecondActivity class name.
6. just put pointer on it (Alt + Enter) and select set package. Error will be gone.
7. Add you newly activity in manifest.
8. done. 
9. Rest is your code in new activity ....